# mySQL SELECT from one table, JOIN from another, then SELECT from the new one

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, join

I have an recruiting database that looks like this: Recruiter has many Students. Students have many "contacts" (how many times we have called/emailed etc.)
I want a recruiter to be able to see when the last time each student of theirs was contacted. I'm developing this app in c# and my database is mySQL.

My table names are employee, students, contact_his and the fields I want to join, given one employeeid are employee.idemployee + students.employee_id then join all of those to contact_his.students_id + students.idstudents. But I have no idea how joins work.. My current code looks like this, but it does not like it:

```
"SELECT students.* FROM admissions.students 
WHERE students.employee_id='PASS VARIABLE HERE' 
JOIN contact_his ON contact_his.students_id = s.idstudents 
WHERE c.date = (SELECT MAX(date);"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT s.*, MAX(h.date) last_contact
FROM students s
JOIN contact_his h ON h.students_id = s.idstudents
WHERE s.employee_id = 'PASS VARIABLE HERE'
GROUP BY s.idstudents
```

Comment: Okay maybe I was premature on that, that didn't seem to work. That only pulls one value from the database. So if I am logged in as 'AAA0000' who has 4 students, it only pulls the student with the highest ID number, I need it to pull all student with their longest ago date.

Comment: Fixed it, I forgot the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Thanks for real this time :)